# Seat Naming Issue in (Jquery-Seat-Charts) Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have seats named as characters from A to Z, But also have some seats which are named like: AA, AB, AC and so on.

When I name a seat in two characters like AA or AB, The layout for these seats is broken and an empty seat (with no label or id) is shown after each seat, like shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnpJM.jpg) !

I tried to change the name to A_A or _A_A but it didn't work.

I think the problem is in this line of the plugin, jquery.seat-charts.js:387

```
$.each(characters.match(/[a-z_]{1}(\[[0-9a-z_]{0,}(,[0-9a-z_ ]+)?\])?/gi), function (column, characterParams) {
```

Any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: It looks like you need to add more code _into your question_. Please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: File a bug report with the author of the library.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I already did that but no response!

Comment: @MostafaAttia: You did it just _two hours ago_. Wait longer.

Comment: From the project's README: _"Each single character represents a different type of seat"_ Why do you expect multi-character seat names to work?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Because there are 1001 seats in my SeatingMap, so I have seats from A-Z and then AA, AB and so on.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I just don't understand why you expect it to work, when the documentation says it won't.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the plugin to make it work :)

Comment: In the question you are using Upper case, but in the code only lower case supported

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I use Uppercase and it works fine just as lowercase,
The problem is that the plugin only supported ONE character for naming seats, I want to modify the plugin to support more than one character, it should be that line of code i posted in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding ID to my seat map like this:

```
'W[AA1]W[AA2]W[AA3]W[AA4]'
```

and then use the id in the setting array of a seat:

`this.settings.id`